# Documentation: the <param> shows up in method summary

Tags: .net, documentation

So I have basically started documenting a class library I made, this is  the first time I'm doing a serious documenting (usually only do the `<summary>`) since it needs more info about some of the parameters used.

When I write:

```
///<summary>Method description.</summary>
///<param name="parameterName">Description of the parameter</param>
```

it displays "Method description. Description of the parameter" when looking in the intellisens for that method, what I want is for it to only show the summary and when writing the parameters for that method show the description of the parameter.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using ? For me it's working fine in VS2008 and VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only blame the lack of sleep, It appears I did this formatting for ALL but 1 method which had `<summary><param></param></summary>` and of-course I was looking at only that method when checking to see if everything was the way I wanted it.
Stupid I know but I found the problem at last...